# Entity Framework database sync

Tags: asp.net

I have a project(ASP.NET MVC 5) on TFS, with an Entity Framework database. 
There are two parts to this question:
 1. I am unable to pull down any stored data in the database.
 2. I cannot see the tables added to the database.

What could be the problem?
Update: I get a null reference due to the fact that I don't have data in the database.

Comment: How are you trying to pull the data from the database? Have you got a valid connection string? Do you get any erros/execptions?

Comment: I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." null reference error, when I try to access the data base entities. 

P.s When I look at the data context, I am able to see all the tables, but not on server explorer

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks Izzy, but I think the reason I get a  null reference is because I have no data in the local database.